# Convert matrix of Z values to colors in R

Tags: r

I'm using persp3d and I need to figure out what colors to use for the plot based on my z values. I have a matrix of z values (a 90 x 201) matrix and the z values range from 3E-39 to 1.3.

How can I figure out a list of colors to use as the color param of persp3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you are referring to `persp3D` from the **GA** package. If so, here's what I'd suggest.)

---

1. Have a look at `jet.colors`, the default value of `persp3D`'s `color.palette=` argument:

   ```
   library(GA)
   jet.colors
   # function (n) 
   # {
   #     palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", 
   #         "cyan", "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))
   #     palette(n)
   # }
   ```
2. Use it as the model for a function of your own. (See `?colorRampPalette` for some insight into how it works):

   ```
   USA.colors <- function(n) {
       palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue"))
       palette(n)
   }
   ```
3. Try it out:

   ```
   ## Adapted from example in ?persp3D
   y <- x <- seq(-10, 10, length=60)
   f <- function(x,y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
   z <- outer(x, y, f)
   persp3D(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5,
           color.palette = USA.colors)
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
     rainbow(length(z))[rank(z)]
```